# How to reduce CPU utilization of a queries which are running at the same time by doing union all

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

High CPU Utilization issue reported to me while generating a report.
In report related procedure, it's been identified that 6 to 7 types of queries (logic for each query is different) are executing by doing UNION ALL as shown in the SQL query. Each query is using 10 to 12 tables and joining each other. And All output columns are referencing almost all the tables using in each query.

Entire query execution time is about 30 seconds to 40 seconds. There is no issue with performance of query. But CPU utilization is taking 50% only for this query. If multiple user generate same report at the same time, then CPU utilization is >99%.

I need suggestions on how to reduce CPU utilization.

Note: Provide sample query is just for reference purpose and it will not execute.

```
SELECT SUM(QTY) QTY, SUM(RATE) RATE, COALESCE(CITY_ADDR,STATE_ADDR) ADDR,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT PRODUCT, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PRODID) PRODUCT
       C.CUSTOEMR
FROM TBLINVENTORY I 
INNER JOIN TBLPRODUCT P
INNER JOIN TBLCUSTOMER C
LEFT JOIN TBLADDRESS A
--- LIKE THIS JOINING 12 TABLES 
WHERE I.ID = 1234 AND C.CUSTOMERID = 4567
GROUP BY ADDR,PRODUCT, CUSTOMER

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(QTY) QTY, SUM(RATE) RATE, COALESCE(CITY_ADDR,STATE_ADDR) ADDR,
       LISTAGG(DISTINCT PRODUCT, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PRODID) PRODUCT
       C.CUSTOEMR
FROM TBLINVENTORY I 
INNER JOIN TBLPRODUCT P
INNER JOIN TBLCUSTOMER C
LEFT JOIN TBLADDRESS A
--- LIKE THIS JOINING 12 TABLES 
WHERE I.ID = 1234 AND C.CUSTOMERID = 4567
GROUP BY ADDR,PRODUCT, CUSTOMER

UNION ALL
...
```

Comment: What is the explain plan for the query? Can't tell much just by looking at the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your query might be using a large amount of CPU because of [concurrent execution of union all](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/types-parallelism.html#GUID-1F4C90F9-3EF5-423A-B55B-2593FB3F1433). Since 12.1, queries with `UNION ALL` may run each branch in parallel to improve performance. To turn off that feature, use the hint `/*+ NO_PQ_CONCURRENT_UNION */`. If a different kind of parallelism is used, the `/*+ NO_PARALLEL */` hint may help.

To check if parallelism is being used, run the below queries to find the SQL_ID of the relevant statement and then generate the execution plan for that SQL_ID. In the execution plan, if you see operations with names like "PX", then parallelism is being used.

```
select sql_id, sql_fulltext from gv$sql where lower(sql_fulltext) like lower('%LISTAGG(DISTINCT PRODUCT%');
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'Enter SQL_ID here'));
```

Alternatively, there may be a way to refactor the `UNION ALL` out of your query, perhaps using `UNPIVOT`.